# Ionic angular service only return data after controller call

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, ionic-framework

I have a service that do two $http.get to get data from two source and concat into an array and return it to controller.

```
angular.module('starter.controllers').factory('GetDataList', function ($http) {
var arrDataList = [];
var postData1 = {
    "param": "1"
};

var postData2 = {
    "param": "2"
};

$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://localhost/search',
    data: postData1
})
.then(function (items) {
    debugger
    arrDataList = arrDataList.concat(items.data.list);
});

$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://localhost/locate',
    data: postData2
})
   .then(function (items) {
   debugger
   arrDataList = arrDataList.concat(items.data.list);
   });

return {
    getAPIData: function () {
        debugger
        return arrDataList;
    }
};
});
```

In my controller, I call it like this:

```
$scope.GetList = function () {
   debugger
   $scope.item = GetDataList.getAPIData();

   $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
}
```

When I use the debugger in console, I notice that

1) getAPIData() will be called first but it has data in it

2) Next debugger triggered at the controller which `GetDataList.getAPIData();` does not return any data for `$scope.Item`

3) The last debugger reach $http call which return the data correctly as I observed in the console. But it never reach the controller side afterwards so no data is being displayed in the mobile app

I read about the natural behavior of angular async call so this seems to be normal. But in my case, what should I do to ensure that the data could reach the controller?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve that without loosing performance, you should use $q.all(), so it will keep your request async and it will return the data once all the promises are resolved. Don't try a synchronic approach because that will reduce your performance.
You can use it like this:

Your factory:

```
app.factory('GetDataList', function($q, $http) {
  var promises = [];
  var arrDataList = [];
  var requests = [{
    url: 'https://localhost/search',
    postData: {
      "param": "1"
    }
  }, {
    url: 'https://localhost/locate',
    postData: {
      "param": "2"
    }
  }];

  angular.forEach(requests, function(req) {
    executeRequest(req);
  })

  function resolveData(data) {
    debugger
    if (arrDataList.length === 0) {
      arrDataList = data.data;
    } else {
      arrDataList = arrDataList.concat(data.data);
    }
  }

  function executeRequest(req) {
    var promise = $http({
        url: req.url,
        method: 'GET',
        data: req.postData
      })
      .then(resolveData);

    promises.push(promise)
  }

  return {
    getAPIData: function() {
      debugger
      return $q.all(promises).then(function() {
        return arrDataList
      });
    }
  }

});
```

And your controller:

```
  $scope.GetList = function() {
    debugger
    GetDataList.getAPIData().then(function(item) {
      $scope.item = item
    });

    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
  }
```

What we are doing here is executing each request inside the `requests` array (using its `url` and `postData`) asynchronously and saving the promises inside an array. When `getApiData` is called, it returns a function that will be called after `$q.all(promises)`, that means it will return the data after all those promises are finished (the promises ask if the `arrDataList` is empty and concats the new data if it's not).

This way you get to keep your async calls! And inside the controller you receive a promise instead of the data itself.

Comment: Excellent idea. Thanks for the explanation and the code sample. Really save my day

Answer (score 0):

You should make it to be synchronized as in the below

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,serviceDemo) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

});
app.factory('serviceDemo', function ($http) {
    var arrDataList = [];
    var postData1 = []; var postData2 =[]

    var firstMethod=function(){ 
                $http({ 
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'a.json'
                }) 
                .then(function (response) {
                  console.log(response);
                    postData1=response.data;
                    arrDataList.push(postData1);
            //      console.log(postData1);
                secondMethod();     //put the second method call here
                });
    }
    var secondMethod=function(){
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                  url: 'b.json' 
                })
                   .then(function (response) {
                   postData2=response.data;
                arrDataList.push(postData2);
                   console.log(arrDataList);
                   });
     }
     var getAPIData= function () {
                firstMethod();

                return arrDataList;
     }

    return {
            getAPIData: getAPIData
    };
    });
```

Modification Made:

You need to call the second method inside the success block of your first method. By this way your first method gets executed, when the result is fetched your second method gets executed and then only control will come out of the first method block.

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/nJjQr3eOm8HPZRvuxKfj?p=preview)**

Comment: I think he is trying to do it asynchronously, so it would be better to use a $q.all approach instead of chaining the promises.